# Ruby Webdriver. Incorrect output with Minitest Reporters Gem SpecReporter and parallel running

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, minitest

I've configured a testing suite with Minitest, the Minitest::Reporters Gem and a Rakefile. All running with the "parallelize_me!" option

The issue is that the output is not correctly displayed, because it is showing the test case currently executing "Suite_X", and when a test case finish it shows the "test_xxx" result. the final output is like hard to understand if you have a lot of test suites.

I think it would be better if the test case currently executing "Suite_X" not shows because I can put the name in the test case itself like i already did:

```
$ N=4 rake
/home/usuario/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -I"lib:tests" -I"/home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib" "/home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "tests/test_helper.rb" "tests/test_suite_a.rb" "tests/test_suite_b.rb" 
Started with run options --seed 33064


# Running tests with run options --seed 33064:

Suite_A
Suite_A
Suite_ASuite_A

  test_search_suite_a_1                                             PASS (25.09s)
.
Suite_B
  test_search_suite_a_2                                             PASS (25.12s)
.
Suite_B
  test_search_suite_a_3                                             PASS (25.65s)
.
Suite_B
  test_search_suite_a_4                                             PASS (25.67s)
.
Suite_B
  test_search_suite_b_4                                             PASS (13.05s)
.  test_search_suite_b_3                                             PASS (12.64s)
.  test_search_suite_b_1                                             PASS (13.58s)
.  test_search_suite_b_2                                             PASS (16.41s)
.
Finished in 41.52647s
8 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


Finished tests in 41.526445s, 0.1926 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.


8 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Minitest Reporters: Mean Time Report (Samples: 13, Order: :avg :desc)
Avg: 16.581905858 Min: 0.0          Max: 33.548447061 Last: 0.0          Description: Suite_A
Avg: 14.896940034 Min: 0.0          Max: 30.567633492 Last: 15.852995213 Description: Suite_B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `parallelize_me` uses threading and the Minitest::Reporter gem doesn't handle this case. If you wanted you could add synchronization to the threads during their reporting however it's probably going to be a pain because I'm pretty sure the reporter gem works over a series of callbacks, so you'd essentially have to synchronize each test run which kind of defeats the purpose.

Alternatively, you could have each thread print to a different IO and handle those however you want to (print at end of run for example)

In my opinion you're best off just not using that Reporter with `parallelize_me`